# How to retrieve Google contacts

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

November 2013, I had changed my phone and I did not face any problem retrieving my all contacts through my Gmail account. After that, in my new phone (Gionee E6), I kept saving all contacts in one of the options (Google). Unfortunately yesterday I lost my phone. Today when I am trying to retrieve my contacts, I could  retrieve only those contacts which were saved before November 2013 (when I had changed my phone.

Moreover, on my desktop Gmail it is showing 6800 contacts whereas in my mobile, after sync, I find about 6000.

Is there any way I could retrieve contacts saved during last 4-5 months?

Comment: That rather sounds as if your "new contacts" have never been synced (maybe sync was turned off?). If that's the case: No way without physical access to your lost device.

Comment: @Izzy If that were the case, they wouldn't show up in Gmail from the desktop machine.

Comment: @DanHulme OP didn't state the 800 additional contacts are the new ones entered, or that the new ones are showing up in Gmail from the desktop machine. Though this seems to be a logical assumption, admitted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "Other" contacts you refer to i.e the 800 which do not show up on your phone (I am going to presume that they are valid and have numbers in them as well) are not assigned to "My Contacts".

If they are in a different group, try shifting them all to where the other 6000 contacts lie. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can login to your Google Contacts at http://contacts.google.com and see all your contacts in the web browser.